# Fire event when mesh position updated in Babylon.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mesh, babylonjs

I have a react app, and when I type in a text box it updates the position of a mesh inside a BabylonJS canvas. I need to be able to do this in reverse - update the text box when a gizmo is used to move the mesh. I don't know if this is possible with an event or another way.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onDragObservable for instance 
Doc:  https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/gizmo